# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/instantapps/InstantApps;' in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/instantapps/InstantApps;'.

I am trying to work with a Native Kotlin SDK with Xamarin.Android but facing the above-mentioned error during runtime.

I tried to install  Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.InstantApps dependency from Nuget package manager but still the error has not been resolved.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an indication of improperly setup Proguard/R8. So either disable it or configure it to keep those classes.